# Does my product infringe on claim 1 of EP 2342386 A1?

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement, claims

I am producing a rainwater collection system and am not sure if the current system infringes on Nigel O'driscoll's [*Rainwater harvesting system* (EP 2342386 A1)](https://www.google.co.uk/patents/EP2342386A1), which is listed as follows:

[image: Nigel O'driscoll's *Rainwater harvesting system* invention.]

> 1. A system for harvesting the rainwater collected from the roof of a building, comprising: a number of rainwater collectors connected to a
>      guttering attached to the roof; a storage tank; and a feed system
>      connecting the rainwater collectors to the storage tank; wherein
>
>    - the feed system comprises a common pumping system connected to the collectors;
>    - each rainwater collector comprises a sensor for detecting when a predetermined level of rainwater has been collected; and
>    - the feed system comprises means for operating the common pumping system so as to transfer water from the collectors to the storage tank
>        only while the amount of water in each of the collectors is greater
>        than or equal to the predetermined level.

The draft for my patent is as follows:

[image: My invention drawing.]

> The invention claimed is:
>
> 1. A rain collecting device comprising:
>
>    - a funnel formed of a polymeric material;
>    - a rainwater storage device;
>    - a pipe to channel rainwater into said rainwater storage device;
>    - a water level meter; and
>    - a tap further comprising: a funnel; and a turning wheel to control supply.
> 2. A rain collecting device as claimed in claim 1, wherein said funnel is comprised of a tube and a collecting basin.
> 3. A rain collecting device as claimed in claim 1, further comprising a display system and means of collecting data.
> 4. A rain collecting device as claimed in claim 4, wherein said water level meter further comprises a direct control method using a
>      wheel.
> 5. A rain collecting device as claimed in claim 1, wherein said tap is arranged such that collected rain will be released when a torque
>      is applied.
> 6. A method for storing rainfall measurements comprising:
>
>    - a software system using Microsoft Word to export data; and
>    - a web-based system to store subsequent Microsoft Word documents.
> 7. A method for storing rainfall measurements as claimed in claim 6, wherein said Microsoft Word documents use a pre-defined template.

Does my patent (particularly claims 1 through 5) infringe O'driscoll's patent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that patents never infringe other patents. It is never patent infringement to file a patent, because filing a patent does not fall under the excludable rights of making, using or selling an invention. A patent is just a description, not an actual working device.

The interesting question is whether it would be possible to build a rain collecting device falling within your Claim 1 and outside O'driscoll's Claim 1. The simplest way to do this would be to omit a "common pumping system" required by O'driscoll's Claim 1 but not by your Claim 1.